# Understanding float variable comparison in if()

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

Unable to find the reason for the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float f = 0.1;
    if (f == 0.1)
      printf("True");
    else
      printf("False");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is false.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float f = 0.1;
    if (f == (float)0.1)
      printf("True");
    else
      printf("False");
    return 0;
}
```

Now shows the correct output. Whats the reason behind this?

Also what is the reason of this behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n = 0, m = 0;
        if (n > 0)
            if (m > 0)
                    printf("True");
        else 
            printf("False");
}
```

Comment: Please never compare floating point numbers for equality. Floating point numbers almost never compare equal.

Comment: Duplicate literally dozens of times.

Comment: ..and C tag opens today's 'annoying question' competition with an old classic. (credit: [Martin James](http://stackoverflow.com/users/758133/martin-james))

Comment: @H2CO3 thank you for pointing that. I searched previously failed to get the same. I will take a look at the answer.

Comment: @Megharaj You're welcome - you may also profit from reading [this](http://floating-point-gui.de) often-cited article.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks a lot for all the information.

Comment: @FUZxxl There are plenty of opportunities for using floating-point equality properly. Your advice is misplaced. Floating-point equality works. In this particular example it is the conversion from `double` to `float` that may produce results surprising to the naive programmer, not equality.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Can you elaborate? I can not figure out a sensible case where it actually makes sense to compare floating point numbers for equality; except perhaps, in case you want to sort them, but even then you can compare with greater-then.

Comment: @FUZxxl With the knowledge that `HUGE_VAL` is `+inf` for IEEE 754 systems, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421756/weverything-yielding-comparing-floating-point-with-or-is-unsafe . For another example, this post contains a function to convert from `double` to `unsigned long long` without using a conversion; the function uses floating-point equality: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/01/A-conversionless-conversion-function2

Comment: @PascalCuoq This is a case for which you have the function isinf() on any C99 compliant system. It is not guaranteed that if something compares equal to HUGE_VAL on non IEEE 754 compliant systems it is really equal to positive infinity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0.1` literal is `double`. You loose precision here `float f = 0.1;`

You could say we loose precision during comparison again, so why isn't `f == 0.1` true anyway? Because `float` extends to `double`, not the opposite. In C smaller type always extends to the bigger one.

Simplified your example we can say that `double(float(1.0)) != 1.0`

Possible solutions:

- use `double` instead of `float` as a type of `f`.
- use cast as in your 2nd example
- use `float` literals - replace all `0.1` with `0.1f`

**Better solution**

Floating point variables have a lot of problems with comparisons. They, including this one, can be solved by defining your own comparison function:

```
bool fp_equal(double a, double b, double eps = FLT_EPSILON) {
  return fabs(a - b) < fabs(eps * a);
}
```

---

The second part of the question:

Why the answer is false is because `else` part always corresponds to the innermost `if` block. So you were confused by formatting, the code is equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    if (n > 0) {
        if (m > 0) {
            printf("True");
        }
        else {
            printf("False");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another solution is to use a float literal `f`, `float f = 0.1f; if (f == 0.1f)` ...

Comment: @AlterMann, it's written in my asnwer. Note the 3rd bullet point.

Comment: @sasha Please can you answer for my third example in the question(just now edited)

Comment: @Megharaj, for your third example, put brackets before each `if` and see what happens :)

Comment: @Megharaj: that last part doesn't really belong under your original question. Don't do unrelated ".. while I have your attention .." questions.

Comment: @sasha.sochka thanks a lot for the answer. Its bad on me that I dint notice that.

Comment: You probably should account for the magnitude of the floating-point values when doing such a comparison. http://www.c-faq.com/fp/fpequal.html

Comment: Rather than use the magic number `1e-20`, consider `FLT_EPSILON` or some factor of it.

Comment: You fixed the magnitude problem, but it still won't work if `a` is negative.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your second question (third example):**

According to your indention, the code doesn't do what you exepect it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{ 
    int n = 0, m = 0;
        if (n > 0)
            if (m > 0)
                 printf("True");
        else 
            printf("False");
}
```

Here the `else` belongs to the inner `if`, so it's equal to

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{ 
    int n = 0, m = 0;
        if (n > 0) {
            if (m > 0) {
                 printf("True");
            } else {  
                 printf("False");
            }
        }
}
```

but I think you meant:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{ 
    int n = 0, m = 0;
        if (n > 0) {
            if (m > 0) {
                 printf("True");
            }
        } else {  
            printf("False");
        }
}
```

It's a good example for why one should alwys user brackets in `if` statements.

Comment: And proper indentation. And a return type for `main`.

Comment: @Ligthness absolutely correct