# Why do I get warning C4756: overflow in constant arithmetic when returning float::PositiveInfinity?

Tags: floating-point, c++-cli, overflow

I have some code which returns float::PositiveInfinity to indicate that an event will never happen but for some reason the compiler (MS Visual Studio 2013) gives me the following warning:

```
warning C4756: overflow in constant arithmetic
```

The code in question looks like this:

```
property float MinsRemainingUntilNextEvent
{
    virtual float get()
    { 
        return float::PositiveInfinity;
    }
}
```

What does that mean and should I care? [MS's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s2sw05.aspx) didn't explain it for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would bet that the implementors of the compiler chose to emit the warning for any floating-point expression that could be evaluated at compile-time and the result of which was `+inf`, meaning that the warning would systematically be emitted for `float::PositiveInfinity`.

Your use of `float::PositiveInfinity` is completely valid and harmless. Ignore the warning. I would like to recommend you get a better compiler but GCC is [similarly silly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421756/weverything-yielding-comparing-floating-point-with-or-is-unsafe) when it comes to floating-point.

Comment: Thanks; I changed my code to use float::MaxValue in the end as that will work in my instance and doesn't raise a warning.